# openGL linear depth information

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to implement Screen Space rendering fluid but I have a trouble with getting depth information.

the depth image I have got is too white.I think is because the depth is not linear.When I look this image very close, it will have a reasonable performance, I can see the depth change. In the same circle, colour in the centre is black and the colour will become white and white when it close to the edge.

So I do a linear for the depth, it looks better but the depth also won't change in the same circle. here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 400

uniform float pointScale;

layout(location=0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 viewMat, projMat, modelMat;
uniform mat3 normalMat;

out vec3 fs_PosEye;
out vec4 fs_Color;

void main() 
{

vec3 posEye = (viewMat * vec4(position.xyz, 1.0f)).xyz;
    float dist = length(posEye);
    gl_PointSize = 1.0f * (pointScale/dist);

    fs_PosEye = posEye;
    fs_Color = vec4(0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0f);
    gl_Position = projMat * viewMat * vec4(position.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

here is my fragment shader:

```
#version 400
uniform mat4 viewMat, projMat, modelMat;
uniform float pointScale;   // scale to calculate size in pixels

in vec3 fs_PosEye;
in vec4 fs_Color;

out vec4 out_Color;
out vec4 out_Position;

float linearizeDepth(float exp_depth, float near, float far) {
return  (2 * near) / (far + near - exp_depth * (far - near));
}

void main()
{
    // calculate normal from texture coordinates
    vec3 N;
    N.xy = gl_PointCoord.xy* 2.0 - 1;
    float mag = dot(N.xy, N.xy);
    if (mag > 1.0) discard;   // kill pixels outside circle
    N.z = sqrt(1.0-mag);

    //calculate depth
    vec4 pixelPos = vec4(fs_PosEye + normalize(N)*1.0f,1.0f);
    vec4 clipSpacePos = projMat * pixelPos;
    //clipSpacePos.z = linearizeDepth(clipSpacePos, 1, 400);
    float depth = clipSpacePos.z / clipSpacePos.w;
    //depth = linearizeDepth(depth, 1, 100);
    gl_FragDepth = depth;
    float  diffuse = max(0.0, dot(N, vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0)));
    out_Color = diffuse * vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    out_Color = vec4(N, 1.0);
    out_Color = vec4(depth, depth, depth, 1.0);
}
```

I want to interpolation based on normal after linear.